# kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__ is raising the error "TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm relatively new to programming, little over 8 months or so, but I am learning kivy and python3 and I am attempting to create a password managing application and I would like for it to open a new screen when a button is pressed. but I am getting a Type Error.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class LoginScreen(Widget):
    pass

class PasswordScreen(Widget):
    pass

class PasswordApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='login'))
        sm.add_widget(PasswordScreen(name='passwords'))

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PasswordApp().run()
```

heres the .kv code

```
<LoginScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Goto passwords'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'passwords'
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'
<PasswordScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
        Button:
            text: 'logout'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'login'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LoginScreen` and `PasswordScreen` extend `Widget`, and the `Widget` `__init__()` does not support a `name` property. Both those classes should extend `Screen` instead of `Widget`.